# page header in lncs format

Tags: header-footer, lncs

In lncs format page headers, even pages have authors name and odd pages have the paper title. I want to change the paper title to section names. 
As in, in odd page headers I want the section/chapter name and the page number to appear. How to change this?

Comment: If you plan to submit this paper (article/book) your change to the page headers will be rejected, most likely

Comment: Please tell us more at to *why* you want to make this change -- or, for that matter, why you're considering using the `lncs` document class if you're intent on making such major changes to the layout of the document class.

Comment: It is my thesis report and my mentor wanted the chapter name in the  page header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `\sectionmark` - the macro responsible for placing marks when you use `\section`. For example, adding

```
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
```

to your preamble with put the section title in the odd (right) header.

Here is a complete example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter  % start of an individual contribution

\title{A title}

\author{An author}
\institute{An institute}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is an abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section{A section}
\lipsum[1-17]
\subsection{A subsection}
\lipsum[1-17]

\end{document}
```